# Compute daily explained variance

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, pca, eigenvalue

I want to use R to estimate the daily explained variance for a fixed number of eigenvectors (which is the same as the "Absorption Ratio" defined by Kritzman et al in [this article](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2Ffinlunch%2FFall10%2FPCASystemicRisk.pdf&ei=5Lj9VKveF4v6ywPrjYGwAw&usg=AFQjCNEnEpVG6itQUVoeR98-PP_zMEQfZg)). I'm using [this data file](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/10_Industry_Portfolios_daily.zip), which is a matrix of daily returns. My main goal is to estimate the daily explained variance (absorption ratio) in the same way as Kritzman et al did it in their article above. On the estimation, Kritzman et al say:

*In order to estimate the absorption ratio, we use a* [rolling] *window of 500 days to estimate the covariance matrix and eigenvectors, and we fix the number of eigenvectors at approximately 1/5 the number of assets in our sample.*

In order to compute this in R I've tried the following codes:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library("quadprog")

# read data set consisting of daily returns
data <- read.table("10_Industry_Portfolios_Daily.txt", header=TRUE)
Ret <- data[,2:ncol(data)]/100
names <- c("NoDur","Durbl","Manuf","Enrgy","HiTec",
           "Telcm","Shops","Hlth","Utils","Other")
colnames(Ret) <- names

# lookback period in number of days (rolling window)
lb.period <- 500
nRow <- nrow(Ret)
nCol <- ncol(Ret)
n <- nRow-lb.period

ar <- rep(0,n) # reserve space for daily absorption ratio
for(i in 1:n) {
# define rolling window
  start <- i
  end <- i+lb.period-1
  ret <- Ret[start:end,]
  cov <- cov(ret)
  eigenval <- eigen(cov)$values
  sumeigenval <- sum(eigenval)
  abs <- eigenval[1:2]/sumeigenval # variance explained by 2 eigenvectors
  ar[i] <- ar[i]+abs # daily variance explained, out of sample period
}
```

When I run this program I get the following warning message; "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length", and end up with a ar[i] vector consisting of *n* equal numbers.

I'm pretty confident that this is the right way to compute the explained variance for 2 eigenvectors

```
  ret <- Ret[start:end,]
  cov <- cov(ret)
  eigenval <- eigen(cov)$values
  sumeigenval <- sum(eigenval)
  abs <- eigenval[1:2]/sumeigenval
```

but my question is how I compute this number on a daily basis using a rolling window approach, as Kritzman has done it in his article. My R knowledge doesn't cut it here, I'm afraid, so I would be very grateful if someone here could help out me on this one. Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

Comment: I also found [this article](https://systematicedge.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/equity-bond-exposure-management/) where the author in fact publishes his R codes related to the estimation of the Absorption Ratio, but it didn't work when I tried my data file with his codes. Still, you might find some programming inspiration here.

Comment: I don't have access to your data (a reproducible example would go a long way), but you could start debugging the offending part yourself. Either put `browser()` before the chunk you think is causing problems (and run the loop) or manually define `i` (e.g. `i <- 3`) and go through the loop step by step.

Comment: I did share the data I am using in the first post, but I can share it once again:
http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/10_Industry_Portfolios_daily.zip
I will continue to work on this, so I will try your suggestions as well. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: @Captain_Slow Hi, I know that this was posted a few years ago. I am currently interested in implementing the absorption ratio.. did you end up solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got this working. Not that it's proof, but the results seem reasonable.

I suspect that this was due to the shape of the data. I'm also sure that this could be made faster and more elegant, but here goes ...

```
library(tidyverse)

# site <- 'http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/10_Industry_Portfolios_daily_TXT.zip'

# Import downloaded data
data <- read_table2(
  file = "10_Industry_Portfolios_Daily.txt", 
  col_types = cols(
    NoDur = col_date(format = "%Y%m%d")
    ), 
  skip = 9
  ) %>% 
  group_by(NoDur) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(NoDur)) %>% 
  mutate_if(.predicate = is.numeric, .funs = ~.x/100)

head(data)

# A tibble: 6 x 10
  NoDur         Durbl     Manuf   Enrgy    HiTec    Telcm   Shops     Hlth   Utils    Other
  <date>        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1926-07-01  0.0002  -0.0028   -0.0023  0.00570 -0.0021  -0.0002 -0.0001   0.0097  0.00610
2 1926-07-02  0.00290  0.0107    0.0081  0.0064   0.0036   0.0026  0.0001   0.0013  0.00470
3 1926-07-06  0.00240  0.0072    0.0022  0.0017   0.00470  0.0017 -0.0023   0.0023  0.0073 
4 1926-07-07  0.0027   0.000600  0.0023 -0.0004  -0.001    0.0032 -0.00580  0.0033  0.0017 
5 1926-07-08  0.0069   0.0005    0.0015  0.00120  0.00350  0.004  -0.0036   0.0091 -0.002  
6 1926-07-09 -0.0039  -0.0115   -0.011  -0.016   -0.0073   0.0021  0.004   -0.0028 -0.0074
```

Once you have this data in the right shape, you can then continue with your original code ...

```
Ret <- data[,-1]

# lookback period in number of days (rolling window)
lb.period <- 500
nRow <- nrow(Ret)
nCol <- ncol(Ret)
n <- nRow-lb.period

ar <- rep(0,n) # reserve space for daily absorption ratio
for(i in 1:n) {
  # define rolling window
  start <- i
  end <- i+lb.period-1
  ret <- Ret[start:end,]
  cov <- cov(ret)
  eigenval <- eigen(cov)$values
  sumeigenval <- sum(eigenval)
  abs <- eigenval[1:2]/sumeigenval # variance explained by 2 eigenvectors
  ar[i] <- ar[i]+abs # daily variance explained, out of sample period
}
```

Bringing this together with the data yields the following ...

```
ar_new <- c(rep(NA, lb.period), ar)
results <- bind_cols(data, Absorption = ar_new)
tail(results)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
  NoDur         Durbl    Manuf     Enrgy    HiTec    Telcm     Shops    Hlth   Utils    Other Absorption
  <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2019-06-21 -0.0027  -0.002   -0.00470   0.00610 -0.0026  -0.0069   -0.0034  0.002   0.00470      0.663
2 2019-06-24 -0.002   -0.00410  0.000600 -0.0092  -0.0005  -0.000600 -0.0045 -0.006  -0.0031       0.663
3 2019-06-25 -0.0027  -0.00350 -0.0045   -0.0078  -0.0184  -0.0068   -0.0065 -0.003  -0.0072       0.663
4 2019-06-26 -0.00940  0.0055  -0.0013    0.0174   0.0068  -0.0086    0.0017 -0.0125 -0.0178       0.663
5 2019-06-27  0.0026   0.0125   0.0028   -0.0083   0.00470  0.005     0.0053  0.0077  0.0017       0.662
6 2019-06-28  0.0036   0.00610  0.0095    0.0108   0.00350  0.0071    0.0016  0.0069  0.0075       0.661
```

... from which we can generate the following chart ...

```
results %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = NoDur, 
      y = Absorption
    )
  ) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "", 
    y = "", 
    title = "Absorption Ratio over Time"
    )
```

[image: Absorption ratio over time]